# Where can I temporarily store file uploads in a React multi step form?

Tags: reactjs, forms, file-upload, session-storage

So, I have a multi-step form that is dynamically built depending on the user's answers. The created form can have multiple "file upload" steps.

In the proof of concept, we used the `sessionStorage` to store all the data from all the steps. And at the last step, when clicking the "submit" button, all the data is sent to the server. However, the `sessionStorage` has a limit (of 5MB, if I am not mistaken).

As a solution, I thought about uploading (using `axios` or something similar) all the files to the server side whenever the user finishes a "file upload" step. Since the user can go back to previous steps of the form and possibly remove some files already sent to the server, I will need to create a delete logic on the server side, so these changes are reflected.

I am looking for a way to keep the current behavior (send all the data to the server at once) but could not find a helpful link on the web. Is this even possible? Can someone suggest me something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add state to the parent component that houses all the form steps and then store all of the form data in local state. Once you are ready to submit, use the state values to submit.

You can store a file in react state just like you would any other form input. The file will be a variable obtained from event.target.files

Comment: Is there some sort of limit size for the local state? At first glance, my guess is that it's somewhat similar to the local storage

Comment: That's an interesting question. My gut reaction is no, because that would be impractical. App state, whether local or through a state management library, is how all interaction with a system is managed in a react app. If there were a size limit on that, it would be a huge limitation. You'll run into performance issues if you start handling ridiculous amounts of data I'm sure, but an actual cap I doubt. Again, I don't know the exact answer here, that is a question for someone who understands react internals better, or maybe its a question of your browser's storage capacity.

Comment: Just to clarify, local state is temporary, if you refresh everything disappears. We're still on the sam page right? You asked for a temporary holding space.

Comment: Sorry for the huge delay, I ended up missing your question. Yes, temporary. As a disclaimer, I ended up uploading files to the server whenever the user first sent them.   Nevertheless, I've searched a bit, looking for a limit on local state and could not find anything. Thus, I will accept your answer and hopefully someone (maybe me) will confirm your answer in the near future!